# UIWebView not loading mobile twitter (iPad)

Tags: uiwebview, nsurlrequest

I try to load Twitter into my UIWebView Using loadHTMLString (after loading the DOM using an NSURLRequest), now the string I have contains the correct HTML.

It loads the twitter page, but then I only get the black bar showing a progress circle, is anyone familiar with this problem and knows how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you download the html first and try loading the UIWebView with loadHTMLString after?

I think you create some issue with the ajax 'magic' because you don't run the html from the same domain as your ajax calls. And it seems like cross site scripting.

I think you can better use something like this and really load in the twitter homepage.

```
 //Create a URL object.
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
//URL Request Object
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
//Load the request in the UIWebView.
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Comment: The problem is, when you use loadRequest a lot of the changes to the request get lost.

Comment: For example user-agent. And I use a subclass of NSURLRequest which gets transformed back to a NSURLRequest by the loadRequest, which means I am missing some object fields which I require.